# next_permutation have different result after being called in a function

Tags: c++, stl

If I have:

```
bool shuffle(string s){
    return next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end());
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){    
        string m = "abcde5";
    do {
        cout << m << endl;
    } while(shuffle(m));
```

I would get:

abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
abcde5
...
abced5

which is **NOT** what I want

However, if I do:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){    
string m = "abcde5";
do {
    cout << m << endl;
} while(next_permutation(m.begin(), m.end()));
```

I would get

abcde5
abce5d
abced5
abd5ce
abd5ec
abdc5e
abdce5
abde5c
abdec5
abe5cd
abe5dc
abec5d
abecd5
abed5c
abedc5
ac5bde
ac5bed
ac5dbe
ac5deb
ac5ebd
ac5edb
acb5de
acb5ed
acbd5e
acbde5
...
edcba5

which is **what I want**.

What's the difference? I looked up the next_permutation, looks like it returns a bool, so I am really confused now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
bool shuffle(string & s){
                    ^
```

You're passing the same string to the function over and over, because you're taking the string by value, and so not modifying the passed argument.

Answer (score 3):

next_permutation is modifying your string to mantain the current state. With your intermediate function shuffle you modify a copy of the original string. To solve the problem try to define shuffle like this:

```
bool shuffle(string &s)
```